# How i can solve Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' error

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, model-view-controller

This is my route:

```
Route::delete('/projet/update/{id_projet}',[listProjetController::class,"edit"])->name('projet.edit');
```

and this my controller :

```
 public function edit($id)
 {
    $projet = projet::where('id_projet',$id)->first();           
    return view('chef_projet.projetUpdate',compact('projet'));                  
 }
```

but css and javascript do not work in my view,
the error looks like this :
[console error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WkST.png)

Comment: what's your client-side code like?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your method in controller as

```
public function edit($id_projet) { 
    $projet = projet::where('id_projet',$id_projet)->first();

    return view('chef_projet.projetUpdate',compact('projet'));
          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In route you are passing $id_project and in fuction u r getting $id which it cant find thats why its giving error

```
public function edit($id_projet){
$projet = projet::where('id_projet',$id_projet)->first();           
return view('chef_projet.projetUpdate',compact('projet'));}
```